# Why does the Lewis definition of acids specify a PAIR of electrons and not a single electron?

Tags: acid-base

The Lewis definition of an acid is: "*a compound or ionic species which can accept an electron pair from a donor compound.*"

Why does it specify a **pair** of electrons and not just a **single** electron?

I initially thought maybe covalent bonds require a pair of electrons but it says that is not the case here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_bond#One-_and_three-electron_bonds

__

For reference:

Question from textbook :
Which of the following species can act as a Lewis acid?

$\ce{NH3}$
$\ce{F-}$
$\ce{H2 O}$
$\ce{NH4+}$
$\ce{BF3}$   (answer)

I thought the answer was $\ce{NH4+}$  as it could accept an electron, but the Lewis definition specifies accepting a **pair** of electrons.

Thanks.

Comment: If only electrons are transferred you have redox not acid-base reaction.

Comment: You know, could you delete the bad homework second part? Otherwise it's a nice question.

Comment: Thanks Mithoron. In the past I have been asked to provide an example. I also find sometimes there are other parts to the problem I am working on which I have not thought of in my posted question (leading me to the wrong answer) and posting the textbook question below, people often point it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It partially has something to do with the history of acid-base definitions. We started with the Arrhenius definition which was based on the generation of $\ce{H+}$ or $\ce{OH-}$ in aqueous solution, and then to the Bronsted-Lowry definition which moved towards acceptance or donation of $\ce{H+}$. Finally came the Lewis Definition which removed $\ce{H+}$ and left us only with electron *pairs*, to be consistent with the past two definitions. We couldn't just say electrons because that would have included a large class of reactions called redox reactions which are clearly not the same as acid-base.

Now, with respect to your answer to the multiple-choice question:

> I thought the answer was $\ce{NH4+}$ as it could accept an electron, but the Lewis definition specifies accepting a pair of electrons.

There are two points that I would like to draw your attention to:

1. You're right in that $\ce{NH4+}$ is an **acid** (more specifically we call it a conjugate acid), but by the two older definitions.
2. However, $\ce{NH4+}$ cannot accept even one electron in this case. If you draw the Lewis structure, you'll find that although there is a net positive charge, all hydrogens have 2 electrons and the central Nitrogen has eight, fulfilling the octet rule.